# Exported RCP application does not run

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

**Current situation:**
One of our products exported via the Eclipse Product export wizard does no longer run, if the produced .exe is run directly. Unfortunately no error message is shown, the program just stops. I assume that no plug-in is loaded at all.

Interestingly the product runs in the following cases:

- the created .exe is executed in the developer mode:

  - in cmd with `MyApplication.exe -dev`
  - in Eclipse with `Launch an Eclipse application`
- my colleague, who uses the same code, can export the product and run it directly
- the .exe, created by me, can be run on my colleague's PC and another PC

Furthermore I can build and run the other product as usual. Win 7 and Java 7 are installed on the three PCs.

*Log:*

There is a Log file in \configuration:

```
!SESSION 2015-02-05 18:03:17.765    -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1 0 2015-02-05 18:03:19.481
!MESSAGE Could not bind a reference of component com.company.common.utils.Zipper.
The reference is: Reference[name = LogModelProvider, interface = com.company.common.service.ILogModelProvider,
policy = dynamic, cardinality = 0..1, target = null, bind = setLogModelProvider, unbind = unsetLogModelProvider]
```

I am not sure what the message means, but it also appears when the application is running in Eclipse. Therefore I ignored it.
There is no log file in \workspace. The folder .metadata does not exists.

**What might have gone wrong:**
The PDE build and export used to work, till I wanted to use Tycho as build system. Therefore I made the needed changes and finally I could build the two projects. Although the projects showed the same symptoms as described above (one worked, the other not). Therefore I created a SVN branch, committed every change and switched back to the trunk, to be back in the starting position. But the symptoms were not gone. Therefore I assume that I must have changed some setting, which causes the problem.

**What I tried:**
Basically I checked if the code and settings were back in the original state. I also switched the Eclipse workspace and imported the necessary plug-ins again. I also rebooted the PC once or twice.

**Question:**
Did anybody already have a similar behavior? Any hint is welcome.

(I know that my problem description is vague, sorry for that.)

Comment: Are  you sure there are no messages in the .log file in the RCP workspace .metadata directory.

Comment: I added a produced log file, as it contains a message which I have ignored till now. The message does not seem important to me.

Comment: The message is because Declarative Services is trying to inject an `ILogModelProvider` but can't find one. You need an implementation of `ILogModelProvider` declared as a Declarative Service (Eclipse Component) for that to work. Doesn't help with your other problem though...